# Select From mySQL Where CURDATE()

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

In a mySQL table I have an `INT(10)` column `r_insert_time` where I store timestamps.

Now I want to select where r_insert_time = today `CURDATE()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND r_insert_time = CURDATE()
```

Now this returns 0 results despite there are values within today like "1547043955"

I also tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND r_insert_time >= CURDATE()
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND DATE(r_insert_time) = CURDATE()
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND DATE(r_insert_time) >= CURDATE()
```

AND all of them return 0.

Comment: Make it a TIMESTAMP or DATE or DATETIME Column and it will work. They are there for a reason, and the reason is so that things like CURDATE() will work properly, why not use them

Comment: I tied converting it to timestamp in phpMyAdmin and it gives me: Too big precision 10 specified for... And I use timestamps with 10 characters like: 1547043955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check to see if the `my_dt` field is stored as `YYYYMMDD`, as CURDATE() requires.
If it is, you need to force CURDATE() to output as a numeric instead of a string for comparison.

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND r_insert_time = CURDATE() + 0
```

Also, I'm not sure what `r_insert_time` is. Aren't you trying to compare CURDATE() to `my_dt`? In which case it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND my_dt = CURDATE() + 0
```

---

**EDIT:**

After taking another look, it looks like you're using an epoch timestamp. If you want to compare that, you'll need to use something like `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to find the range of epoch times that your timestamp could fall in.

Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdv WHERE u_id = ? AND r_insert_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND r_insert_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + 1)
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, r_insert_time the real name.

Comment: for r_insert_time, it's stored as INT(10) and as follows: 1547043955. It's a php time() value.